# Emitted Image not Showing up on Camera

Tags: rendering, texturing, image, emission

I'm currently working on a scene with a projected image on one of the walls. I've gotten to the point where the imaged is being emitted, but when I check what it looks liked rendered or through the camera it doesn't show up.[image]

Not sure what it is as I already checked to see if it was the lights in the scene that was effecting it and its not. It could be that I'm emitting the image wrong as I was following an older tutorial. Here's an image of the node editor:[image]

Also it's in the eevee engine but it's the same for cycles. Any suggestions or advice would be helpful.

Here's the file:
[image]

Comment: not sure what you mean by delete all but I have attached the blender file if you would like to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera Properties > Lens > **Clip End** 100 **change to above 120 m**.

[image]

Your Camera is clipped in view. You can see Start-End clipping by enabling Camera Properties > Viewport Display > **Limits**

Comment: You're right! Didn't even notice thank you